# Remove small pixels in raster without leaving a gap

Tags: qgis, raster, polygonize

I have converted a raster to shapefile (polygonize) in QGIS and now have some areas that are salt and pepper with small points. I want to absorb these into the large polygon around the pixel (polygon). I know how to delete these but this leaves gaps in the coverage, I want to default to the largest neighbour.

Comment: After deleting small features use Delete Holes algorithm to fill the gaps? Or, use gdal_sieve to remove the smallest groups of pixels before polygonizing.

Comment: @BenW write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Removing small holes from a polygon can be done using:
**Delete Holes** from the **Processing Toolbox**.

[image: Delete Holes Tool]

[image: Delete Holes Input Output]